# Loading Storyboard from AppDelegate leaves black space on window

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, appdelegate

I am launching `Storyboard` from `AppDelegate` but getting black space on top and bottom of screen. Here is my code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *vc =[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    // Set root view controller and make windows visible
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Here is what it looks like :

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason for all that code instead of setting the initial view controller (in the storyboard) and letting default app initialization load the main storyboard?

Comment: @PhillipMills : Yes there is. I want my navigation title to be displayed in white color. For which I am using [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; which I have set in AppDelegate. However, the storyboard is launched first as it is the launch screen. When it gets launched black title appears on navigation. And then AppDelegate is called which sets the title to white. Thus, to avoid the change of color of navigation title at launch, I am doing this.

Comment: @PhillipMills : If you can help me set navigation title color from storyboard itself, I won't be doing all this.

Comment: Putting the `appearance` settings in a `+ (void)initialize` method for either the app delegate or the first view controller seems to work and lets the automatic mechanism take care of storyboard/controller/window connections.

Comment: @PhillipMills : Just tried what you suggested but still faced the same issue. Seems like initialize is called after launch of Storyboard.

Comment: Odd.  I did it in a very simple master/detail example and didn't see any color change at all.  I don't know what the difference might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to you not having a Default-568h@2x.png launch image.

Try adding one or use a launch images from the asset catalog and have one for iPhone 5 size.

(also is: `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];` necessary and does it return what you expect?)